# list box manipulations

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I am using a asp.net listbox. I have two buttons one to add items to listbox and another to remove. I am using javascript function to remove items from the listbox. When I add to the listbox after removing. The removed items are also getting added.

```
<asp:ListBox ID="sLstbox" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="150px" TabIndex="10"></asp:ListBox>

<asp:LinkButton ID="sLbtnAdd" runat="server" ></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp; 
<a href="#" id="hAncRemove" runat="server" onclick="fncRemoveItems();">Remove</a>    

function fncRemoveItems()
{
    var i;
    var strIDs="";
    var items = document.getElementById("sLstbox");
    alert(items.options.length);
    for (i = items.options.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (items.options[i].selected)
            items.remove(i);
    }
}
```

IN code

```
Protected Sub sLbtnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles sLbtnAdd.Click

    Dim li As New ListItem
    li.Value = "1"
    li.Text = "test"
    sLstbox.Items.Add(li)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using normal < select > boxes in this case.
asp:listboxes are meant to be manipulated at server side and you need to hack around that to make it work the way you want.

With normal select-boxes (either runat server or not) it should be pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your life a lot easier and give you the 'AJAX' effect, just put it all in an `UpdatePanel` and do it server side.  If you want to use an `asp:ListBox`, manipulating it via javascript is going to a pain.

Here is a working example with the aspx code and the codebehind implementation for your scenario:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="yourUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="sLstbox" runat="server" Width="250px" Height="150px" TabIndex="10"></asp:ListBox> 
        <asp:LinkButton ID="sLbtnAdd" runat="server" OnClick="sLbtnAdd_Click" ></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;  
        <asp:LinkButton ID="sLbtnRemove" runat="server"  OnClick="sLbtnRemove_Click"></asp:LinkButton>&nbsp;        
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In your codebehind:

```
Protected Sub sLbtnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles sLbtnAdd.Click            
    Dim li As New ListItem      
    li.Value = "1"      
    li.Text = "test"      
    sLstbox.Items.Add(li)      
End Sub 

Protected Sub sLbtnRemove_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles sLbtnAdd.Click            
    For i As Integer = sLstbox.Items.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If sLstbox.Items(i).Selected Then
            sLstbox.Items.Remove(sLstbox.Items(i))
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Aaah, are you sure? A new request for deleting an item from your listbox??

Comment: @Chris van de Steeg I was trying to give him the most simplest solution as an alternative to your answer.  The cost of a new request in his case might not be even measureable vs the cost of implementing a cut and paste solution. OP will have to weigh his options since neither of us knows the scope / evenironment.

Comment: I am doing the removing from the server side and allowing post backs to happen currently.

Comment: @skamale so do you need some other help?  Is the solution I provided working?  Did you do something else? Not sure what else you are looking for.